# MariaDB fails to run a mysql time query

Tags: mysql, time, mariadb, utc

This line was ok in MySQL to show me the change form an hour ago:

```
SELECT FROM Thundersense 
SELECT mB,UTC FROM thundersense WHERE utc BETWEEN UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 HOUR) AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP() LIMIT 1
```

Now I have moved over to MariaBD and it fails, in this case utc it the header in the table

Yours Simon M

OK this is a statement to take the reading from 1 hour ago and compare it to the current reading thus display in rise/fall and how much by. (UTC the name of a column in the table thundersense. Bad choice I know)
I have now solved this one, I was getting the row[0], and row[1] messed up!
thanks any way

Comment: Not a valid sql statement ,select what exactly?

Comment: Please provide the exact error message you are receiving.

Comment: You need to specify the `*` wildcard if you want to return all your fields or provide a list to the fileds that you want to display...